# Can I have climbing plants in a very narrow bed behind garden furniture

Tags: flowers, gravel, patio

I'm creating a small gravel patio up against a fence in the corner of the garden, 2m x 3.5m. I'd like a corner sofa there, but also considering if I can use some of that space for a small flower bed for growing some climbing plants up the fence.

So my question is, how small of a flower bed can I get away with behind a corner sofa to grow flowers. Would this even work as it would be very shaded, or is there a better way. Or should I just gravel it to the fence and not add flowers.

I'm based in the UK.

Comment: Two or three 2-liter pots can grow several annual vines each, such as Morning Glory and Moonflower, for a day & night effect that handles partial shade. Virginia Creeper is a perennial that handles shade, grows 10m, and turns scarlet in the Fall (insignificant flowers).

Comment: Will the corner sofa be a permanent feature during the growing season? I imagine so... a photo of the area might help, but which way does it face, north, south...? Is there a fence at the boundary of the area?

Comment: The patio is at the southern side my south facing garden, the corner fences divide other gardens. The corner sofa would be a permanent feature. I'm leaning towards just getting pots I think